# Automated SQL Email bad results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, email, stored-procedures

I've created an automated email that tells my customers when they've ordered a part that's on back order. It uses one SQL view and 2 stored procedures as listd below. My issue is that when I execute it, the first backorder sends an email with the title 'sql server message' and has no sql results in it. All subsequent backorders run properly with the correct subject and data in the body. Is there something I've done wrong in my sp's?

This sp runs first, and builds a list of our customers that have Backordered parts.

```
USE [001]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [mfg].[sp_BackorderEmailListing]    Script Date: 6/29/2015 4:09:31 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Nicholas Dininno>
-- Create date: <6/15/15>
-- Description: <Runs through a distinct list of Franchisees that have 
-- orders on backorder, and passes their info to [mfg].[sp_SendBackorderEmail]>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [mfg].[sp_BackorderEmailListing]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @cmp_code nvarchar(50)
Declare @email nvarchar(Max)  
Declare cur_BackOrdSP Cursor

For SELECT DISTINCT  [Franchise ID]  FROM [001].[mfg].[Backorder_Report]

Open cur_BackOrdSP

Fetch Next From cur_BackOrdSP

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

Begin
    --find email address
    SELECT @email = [cmp_e_mail] FROM [001].[mfg].[Backorder_Report] where [Franchise ID]=@cmp_code

    execute [mfg].[sp_SendBackorderEmail] @cmp_code, @email

    Fetch Next From cur_BackOrdSP Into @cmp_code
END

Close cur_BackOrdSP
Deallocate cur_BackOrdSP
END
```

The next part is where the email is built.

```
USE [001]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [mfg].[sp_SendBackorderEmail]    Script Date: 6/29/2015 4:12:51 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Nick Dininno
-- Create date: 6/25/2015
-- Description: Sends email to Franchisees with backordered parts
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [mfg].[sp_SendBackorderEmail]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(@cmp_code nvarchar(5), @email nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

DECLARE @profile nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @subject nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @querystr nvarchar (MAX)


set @profile = 'Reports'
set @subject  =  'Backorder Report for ' + @cmp_code
set @querystr = 'SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT  [Order #],[Order Date],[Item #],[Description]
  FROM [001].[mfg].[Backorder_Report]
  WHERE [Franchise ID] = '''+@cmp_code+'''';


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = @profile,
@recipients = 'me@company.com',
@subject = @subject,
@body = 'Note: This is an automatic e-mail message generated by the Parts Department.  

Our records indicate that you ordered the parts shown below.  Unfortunately these parts are currently on backorder.  They will be shipped to you as soon as they become available.  In the meantime, if you have any questions or concerns regarding this order please contact the Parts Department via email parts@lawndoctor.com or call 732-308-2300 x4.

Thank you!
Parts Department
parts@company.com
', 
@query = @querystr

END
```

The recipient me@company.com will be replaced once i'm sure it works with the @email parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue here was a syntax issue. In the first procedure I didn't pass the Franchise ID into @cmp_code.

```
Fetch Next From cur_BackOrdSP
```

Should have been

```
Fetch Next From cur_BackOrdSP into @cmp_code
```